# (WPF)Добавить таблицу в импортированную базу новую таблицу

Tags: c#, wpf

Как добавить таблицу в уже существующую БД, которая находится в проекте
Не запись, а именно добавить новую таблицу
[image: 111]

Comment: база данных - SQLite

Comment: Отредактируйте `ApplicationContext` так, как надо и сделайте миграцию.